# Junit test for method with anonymous code block

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I need write junit test for method which contains anonymous code block, where override some logic. In my test I need verify if that logic works as should.

for instance:

```
public void foo(Bar bar) {
   Foo myFoo = giveMeFoo(bar, new FooCallBack() {

      @Override
      public boolean doSomeLogic(SomeObject obj) {
         if (obj.xxx == null)
            return false;

         // do some algorithm

         reutrn true;
      }
   });
}
```

FooCallBack is interface which is implemented in few methods and I need to write tests for them.

What I need:

1. mock SomeObject obj and test different cases
2. verify if it returned true or false for different bar object

Can you tell me how to do this? Thanks in advice.

Comment: can you please attach the information about how a Foo instance is being received as well as how does the callback being invoked? because for now I can't see a problem with just capturing the callback with ArgumentCaptor and just invoking the callback with different arguments, asserting the result

Comment: create a seperate named class and test that. as for the mocking, you'll need to provide more information

Comment: @AndreyIlyunin FooCallBack is just interface, and method imeplemtation is overided. Foo boject is given by function giveMeFoo, which I want mock as well, and return some explicit written object

Comment: Don't use anonymous classes.

Comment: @Antoniossss unfortunatelly this code is not written by me, I just need test it.

Comment: Unfortunetelly - you wont